# Comparing Two values in a generic method c#

Tags: c#, generics, comparison, operators, operands

I think my code is self explanatory about what i want to achieve :

```
private bool Comparison<T>(T operatorOne, T operatorTwo, string operand)
    {
        switch (operand.ToLower())
        {
            case "=":
                return operatorOne.Equals(operatorTwo);
            case "<":
                return operatorOne < operatorTwo;
            case ">":
                return operatorOne > operatorTwo;
            case "contains":
                return operatorOne.ToString().Contains(operatorTwo.ToString());
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

It gives me error :

```
Error   16  Operator '>','<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
```

I need a method that can compare strings, Int,Double, chars. 
Note: Exclude the condition that strings will be passed for > or < check OR Int will be sent for "contains" check

Comment: You have the concepts of "operator" and "operand" backwards. In the expression `a + b`, `a` and `b` are operands and `+` is an operator.

Comment: Yeah, sorry !! my fault :)

Comment: What do you know about T, if you stipulate `where T : IComparable` you might be able to get away with what you have.

Comment: @mrtig T here in my case can only be int, double, float, decimal, string, char

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [`Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(operatorOne, operatorTwo)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for comparation. Please be aware that if `T` does not implement `IComparable` and `IComparable<T>`, `Comparer<T>.Default.Compare` throws an exception.

To make sure that `T` implements `IComparable`, you may add `where T: IComparable` constraint. (It will exclude classes which implement `IComparable<T>`, *but not* `IComparable`. Still may be acceptable, since many classes which implement `IComparable<T>`, implement `IComparable` too.)

```
private bool Comparison<T>(T operatorOne, T operatorTwo, string operand)
    where T: IComparable
{
    switch(operand.ToLower())
    {
        case "=":
            return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(operatorOne, operatorTwo) == 0;
        case "<":
            return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(operatorOne, operatorTwo) < 0;
        case ">":
            return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(operatorOne, operatorTwo) > 0;
        case "contains":
            return operatorOne.ToString().Contains(operatorTwo.ToString());
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

**P.S.**

As **Servy** suggested, you may also pass `IComparer` as an extra parameter to the function. It would allow to cover types which implement neither `IComparable` nor `IComparable<T>`, so `Comparer<T>.Default` does not work for them.

Also, credits go to **@TimothyShields**, who suggested `Comparer<T>.Default`.

Comment: @isumit With Comparer<T>.Default you could even remove `where` constraint.

Comment: @AlexD You *can* but you *shouldn't*, unless you accept an `IComparer` as a parameter.  The given code will fail at runtime if the type doesn't implement `IComparable<T>`; with the generic constraint the code will fail at compile time if an unsuitable type is used.

Comment: @Servy I was just editing the answer. A slight problem here is that `Comparer<T>.Default.Compare` may return either `IComparable<T>` or `IComparable`, which is hard to express via `where` constraint. We can say `where IComparable` since classes which implement `IComparable<T>` usually implement `IComparable` too. But it still opens a corner case where only `IComparable<T>` is implemented.

Comment: @AlexD That's why I always accept the comparer as a parameter, rather than expecting the default comparer to be implemented.  You see the BCL do the same thing.  This allows types that don't implement either interface to be used.

Comment: @Servy Do you mean to have the comparer as an extra parameter of `Comparison<T>` function? Sure, such comparer can compare whatsoever, but it would change the function signature.

Comment: @AlexD I'd go with an `IComparer`, not a delegate, but the idea is the same.  You could have both overloads if you wanted.  Yes, it would change the function signature; my whole assertion is that doing so would improve the function.